# Create a certificate request using .netstandard 2.0 library

Tags: x509certificate2, .net-standard-2.0

NetStandard 2.0 apparently does not include `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificateRequest'.

So is it not possible to create X509Certificates in a .NETStandard 2.0 library? If not, why not? X509Certificates are included so it seems an odd exclusion.

Comment: it is included in .net standard 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Standard 2.0 was built between .NET Framework 4.6.1 and 4.6.2, and doesn't have types that weren't present in .NET Framework 4.6.2.

`CertificateRequest` was added to .NET Framework in 4.7.2.

The easiest answer is to target either .NET Framework or .NET Core instead of .NET Standard, then the type will become available (provided you use a high enough version).  Alternatively, unless you're using a custom `X509SignatureGenerator`, the type is simple enough that you could bind it with reflection.

```cs
private static X509Certificate2 MakeCert(string certDN, RSA key)
{
    Type certificateRequestType = typeof(RSACertificateExtensions).Assembly.
        GetType("System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificateRequest");

    object request = certificateRequestType.GetConstructor(
        new[] { typeof(string), typeof(RSA), typeof(HashAlgorithmName), typeof(RSASignaturePadding) }).Invoke(
        new object[] { certDN, key, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1 });

    Collection<X509Extension> extensions = (Collection<X509Extension>)
        certificateRequestType.GetProperty("CertificateExtensions").GetValue(request);

    // add things to the extensions collection
    ...

    DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    return (X509Certificate2)certificateRequestType.GetMethod("CreateSelfSigned").Invoke(
        new object[] { now.AddMinutes(-5), now.AddDays(30) });
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that the type will be there so that you can access it by reflection? For me, after I've changed target from net48 to netstandard2.0 `GetType` returns `null`.

Comment: @Yola Updated from Type.GetType to searching in the assembly that defines RSACertificateExtensions (.NET Framework 4.6), since CertificateRequest and RSACertificateExtensions are in the same assembly in all framework versions.

Comment: Nice, thank you, no need in my answer anymore.